# Doxygen for a Python module that's split into multiple files

Tags: python, doxygen

I use Doxygen to document a Python project.  This project includes a module that is split into multiple files.  I needed to do that for maintainability.  Some of the classes in the module are very large with complex implementations.  If I had to combine them all into one file, that file would become unmanageably large, well over 10,000 lines.  So I split them into many files, then have __init__.py import all the files into the parent module.  This works nicely: the code is maintainable, and users can import everything with a single import statement.

But Doxygen doesn't know about this.  It shows all the classes as being split into many modules.  I don't want users to even know all those modules exist.  They're just an implementation detail to keep the code simpler.  How can I make it produce documentation that matches the intended API, with all the classes shown as being in a single module?

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you not use python's built-in documentation interface rather than doxygen? Also I don't think you can hide modules from users; Python allows introspection so even if you make efforts to do so, users will still be able locate your modules.

Comment: Two reasons.  1. My project involves multiple languages, and Doxygen supports all of them.  It lets me produce consistent, unified documentation for everything.  2. Doxygen produces nicer looking documentation.  Also, I should clarify: I'm not worried about hiding things from users that go looking for them.  I just want the documentation to accurately reflect the intended usage.  It should be obvious to users that they can import all the classes with a single import statement, instead of needing a whole bunch of them.

Comment: Thanks - sorry I don't have a solution, I was just curious.